# How can I select in CSS a DIV parent from a specific ID or Class?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to add css style for the specific div class="b" but only the one with the child element div class="c2".

```
    <div class="a" id="a5">
      <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
          <a class="d">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <div class="c2">
          <a class="d">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do that?

Many thanks

Comment: I hope you will find some useful resource here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/15521590

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)